# Alternative 3rd party app for fitbit watch?

Tags: app, fitbit

As a developer and fitness freak, I was curious if the fitbit band is supported by any 3rd party software? I have done some research without much success. I would really appreciate if someones points me in the right direction as to how to make the most out of my fitbit inspire hr.

Comment: I might be proven wrong, but probably not. Fitbit has been notably tight about letting other people interface with their API (I assume as much to prevent a 3rd party hardware manufacturer from making a $20 band that interfaces with their software as to prevent people from writing software that interfaces with their band).

Comment: Couldn't agree more!

Comment: I track my meals with "Lose It!", it support Fitbit API and a bunch of other bands, but I didn't tried it.